# How to raise an attached event in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I raise [DataObject.Pasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.pasting.aspx)  event from my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can raise any event on any `UIElement` using the `RaiseEvent()` method.  Just create the appropriate event args for the handler and pass to `RaiseEvent()`.

```
var args = new DataObjectPastingEventArgs(dataObject, isDragDrop, formatToApply)
{
    Source = this,
    RoutedEvent = DataObject.PastingEvent //set the event here
};
element.RaiseEvent(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx) on the appropriate UIElement, passing in a [RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.aspx) with RoutedEvent set to DataObject.Pasting.